# Change the default edit mode of color picker bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, color-picker

In HTML element, I want to set the default edit mode in input type color to hex as the following image. Normally, the starting mode when you click on the picker is R,G,B mode, then H,S,L and last is Hex. So, I need the hex mode to be the first,
Is that possible ?

[image]